# How output of current transformer is given to voltage divider circuit in given circuit?

Tags: current, transformer, voltage-divider

[image: This is image of the block diagram of the project I am doing.]

This block diagram i have referrd from IEEE paper for reference for doing project
The project is about "Resisdence energy control based on wireless smart socket and Iot.
  In this diagram here CT's output is given to voltage divider. How it works as output of CT is current not voltage.

Comment: Start here: https://learn.openenergymonitor.org/electricity-monitoring/ct-sensors/introduction

Comment: Don’t assume it a divider. Burden Resistor matches suitable impedance of CT which naturally translates current into voltage by high step down current ratio which squares impedance.

Comment: The secondary of the CT feeds a 'burden' resistor often much less than 1 ohm, which converts AC current into a tiny AC voltage that is converted to DC peak or RMS values and amplified as needed.

Answer (score 2):

The output of a current transformer is current, into a very low external resistance called a burden resistor. The purpose of this burden resistor is two-fold.

The first is to develop a voltage across it, proportional to the secondary, and hence primary, current. If the resistance is R, and the turns ratio N, the output of the transformer+resistor combination an overall measurement gain of R/N volts per primary amp.

The second is to keep the current transformer essentially short-circuited. Without it, the transformer could develop a high and dangerous voltage on the secondary. As core flux in a transformer varies as winding voltage, keeping a low value resistor, ie a low voltage, on the secondary means it can handle a higher primary current before saturation, which would make its gain non-linear.

It's possible that when processing the voltage output from the burden resistor, they might follow it with a voltage divider. However that would be wholly unnecessary, as it would be easier and better to simply use a smaller value of burden resistor.